# Angular Protractor: No specs found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automated-tests, protractor

While investigating protractor I got the following issue:

When I ran the following code, it didn't find any specs... so the tests do not run

```
describe('My app', function() {

    console.log('Starting test suite "GUEST"');

    browser.get('')
        .then(function () {

            it('Should automatically redirect', function() {
                console.log('Start test 1: automatic redirection of index');
                expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("/test");
            });

        });

});
```

The redirection has been done correctly, but the output is:

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.10.217:50382/wd/hub
Starting test suite "GUEST"
Started


No specs found
Finished in 0.004 seconds
Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed
```

I think protractor runs through the file and finds the end before the **.then** promise callback function is executed and doesn't find any **expect**s.

I might be doing it all wrong... but it seemed like the way to do it

Comment: you have to run conf.js file and in that, you have to write spec section:
something like this : exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['test.js']}

Answer (score 3):

Your test is wrapped in a promise that gets resolved after the phase of registering the tests. It should be:

```
describe('My app', function() {

    console.log('Starting test suite "GUEST"');

    it('Should automatically redirect', function() {
        browser.get('')
        .then(function () {
                console.log('Start test 1: automatic redirection of index');
                expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toMatch("/test");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse! And what about non promise async calls? My client wants to check some database stuff as well... to check if data is inserted (that is not displayed). The database query function needs a callback function... can I use an expect in that callback function?

Comment: You totally can. If you use mysql take a look at promise-mysql - it's a wrapper that wraps function calls with promises.

Comment: Also you may find it useful to place such asynchronous non-protractor calls in the [control-flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) by using [browser.controlFlow().execute](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/)

Comment: I have tried using the browser.wait() but it didn't do what I wanted... could someone take a look at: http://pastebin.com/kDRhCgBy? If you guys want credit, I could make a new question... I'm using oracledb

Comment: I have also tried to use the controlFlow here: http://pastebin.com/PbphSD6a but I get the same output... the accountsCount remains null... while the result.rows[0][0] outputs the expected 9

Comment: Yes, please ask another question, so that it could be read and answered properly.